# NSKeyedUnArchiver Crash

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, nsexception, nskeyedunarchiver

My app delegate is crashing because of a NSException crash. I used the exception breakpoint tool to pinpoint the place where it is crashing (Added a comment on top of it, inside init()) during NSUnarchiver, and in a file called ItemStore. Please help me fix this bug, I have tried all of my ideas already.

Without the Exception Breakpoint, this is the crash

```
2016-11-29 09:46:42.546 Foodie[3100:386241] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (Photomania.Item) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'
```

When I employ the exception breakpoint, I receive an exception on the starred line below in ItemStore.

ItemStore.swift:

```
import Foundation

class ItemStore {

var allItems: [Item] = []
let itemArchiveURL: NSURL = {
    let documentsDirectories =
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
        inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!
    return documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("items.archive")
    }()

init() {

    // here is the crash
    if let archivedItems =
        NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(itemArchiveURL.path!) as? [Item] {
            allItems += archivedItems
    }
}

func moveItemAtIndex(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) {
    if fromIndex == toIndex {
        return
    }

    // Get reference to object being moved so you can re-insert it
    let movedItem = allItems[fromIndex]

    // Remove item from array
    allItems.removeAtIndex(fromIndex)

    // Insert item in array at new location
    allItems.insert(movedItem, atIndex: toIndex)
}

func createItem() -> Item {
    let newItem = Item(random: true)

    allItems.append(newItem)

    return newItem
}

func removeItem(item: Item) {
    if let index = allItems.indexOf(item) {
        allItems.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}

func saveChanges() -> Bool {
    print("Saving items to: \(itemArchiveURL.path!)")
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(allItems, toFile: itemArchiveURL.path!)
}

}
```

App Delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

// Override point for customization after application launch.

//Create an ImageStore
//let imageStore = ImageStore()
//let itemStore = ItemStore()

//Access the ItemsViewController and set its item store
//let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
//let itemsController = navController.topViewController as! ItemsViewController

//itemsController.itemStore = itemStore
//itemsController.imageStore = imageStore

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let rootController = window?.rootViewController

    if rootController is UITabBarController {
        let firstTabItem = (rootController as! UITabBarController).viewControllers?[0]

        if firstTabItem is UINavigationController {

            let firstController = (firstTabItem as! UINavigationController).viewControllers.first as! ItemsViewController
            firstController.itemStore  = ItemStore()
            firstController.imageStore = ImageStore()
        }
    }
    return true
}

...

}
```

Photomania.Item :

```
import UIKit

class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {

var meal: String
var restaurantName: String?
var valueInDollars: Int
let dateCreated: NSDate
let itemKey: String

init(meal: String, restaurantName: String?, valueInDollars: Int) {
    self.meal = meal
    self.restaurantName = restaurantName
    self.valueInDollars = valueInDollars
    self.dateCreated = NSDate()
    self.itemKey = NSUUID().UUIDString
}

convenience init(random: Bool = false) {
    if random {
        let nouns = ["Meal"]
        let places = ["Restaurant"]

        var idx = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(nouns.count))
        let randomNoun = nouns[Int(idx)]

        idx = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(places.count))
        let randomPlace = places[Int(idx)]

        let randomName = "\(randomNoun)"
        let randomValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
        let randomRestaurantName = "\(randomPlace)"

        self.init(meal: randomName,
            restaurantName: randomRestaurantName,
            valueInDollars: randomValue)
    }
    else {
        self.init(meal: "", restaurantName: nil, valueInDollars: 0)
    }
}

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    meal = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("meal") as! String
    dateCreated = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("dateCreated") as! NSDate
    itemKey = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("itemKey") as! String
    restaurantName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("restaurantName") as! String?

    valueInDollars = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("valueInDollars")

    super.init()
}

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(meal, forKey: "meal")
        aCoder.encodeObject(dateCreated, forKey: "dateCreated")
        aCoder.encodeObject(itemKey, forKey: "itemKey")
        aCoder.encodeObject(restaurantName, forKey: "restaurantName")

        aCoder.encodeInteger(valueInDollars, forKey: "valueInDollars")
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full details of the crash.  What is the exception being raised?  What is the full error and backtrace?

Comment: @JAL I edited my question with details.

Comment: What is `Photomania.Item`?

Comment: @JAL Another file in my project. The application allows the user to create items in a UITableView and upload a picture of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did'nt show your Photomania.Item class/struct but it should conform to NSCoding protocol.Take a look on this example :
http://mhorga.org/2015/08/25/ios-persistence-with-nscoder-and-nskeyedarchiver.html

Comment: I do not understand how this applies to my class. I tried to insert the example materials but there were many errors. I added the original Photomania.Item class to the bottom of my question.

Comment: you've added ItemStore again, I don't see  the Item class

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry

Comment: Try to remove your app and run as your save data was corrupted

Comment: What do you mean? How do I remove my app?

Comment: From the simulator or your device